Windows 11 Home: Windows Hello and Delay Lock Interval
Am I correct to conclude that if I want to use a fingerprint for sign-in to a laptop using Windows 11 Home, I have to enable Windows Hello;  and by doing that, I no longer can have any control over the Lock Time Interval, which will be frozen at "everytime", and immediate, without any delay, whenever I am away?
Is there no way around this?

By "Lock Time Interval", do you mean the period of inactivity after which the lock screen is activated?

@harrymc, Yes, that is what I mean by "lock time interval".  Right now, as soon as that interval reaches a minute, maybe 2, the lock is activated.  It happens too fast, and I am constantly having to sign back in.  BTW, I assume this is the way I am supposed to respond to you?  There is no clear indication on how I can reply to a comment.

@john,  I am a newbie.  I have no idea how or why your comment was voted down.  I don't know what your comment was, and I didn't do it.  Explain to me, if you can, please, thanks

Terminology: This is a "comment", and @John put up an "answer" that someone "downvoted" as wrong, which John then deleted himself. Comments are for anything that is not an answer/solution.
